# Regular expression to validate a string that contains both digit and non-digit characters

Tags: regex, validation

Could anybody help on a regular expression that I can use to validate if a string contains both digit and non-digit characters?

I'm using `"\d+\D+"` but it's not working. The test cases I have are:

```
a1
1a
a1b
1ab
ab1
1-2
12-
-12
```

The test cases I listed should all result in match. I'm using javascript RegExp.test() So 999 or asdf or _+sdf would not match.

Comment: What regex engine/environment if any are you using? What should be the outcome on each of those test cases? And what command (if applicable) are you calling the regex with?

Comment: Please provide examples of valid and INVALID strings. Otherwhise no one could know the difference between them.

Comment: Simple. If: `^(?=\D*\d)(?=\d*\D)` matches, you're good.

Comment: The test cases I listed should all result in match. I'm using javascript RegExp.test() So 999 or asdf or _+sdf would not match. Thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

Your current regex only matches strings of one or more digits, followed by one or more non-digits. You could use a look-ahead to check for the existence of a digit:

```
"(?=.*\d).*\D.*"
```

The `(?=.*\d)` part means "somewhere after this, there must be zero or more of any character followed by a digit." This allows your digit to appear anywhere in the string.

The `.*\D.*` part means "match zero or more of any character, then a non-digit, then zero or more of any character," which will match a non-digit at any position in the string and the rest of the characters (digits or not) around it.

Comment: You sir, musst be a magician to tell from `a1 1a a1b 1ab ab1 1-2 12- -12` which pattern is required... There is no Validation, without KNOWING what is INvalid. will `1a 1a a1b 1ab ab1 1-2 12- -12` be valid?

Comment: @dognose *"validate if a string contains both digit and non-digit characters"*

Comment: After reformating the list, ist clearer. Thought that should go into ONE pattern.

Comment: @arshajii -- that's still not clear. What if there are symbols present, like the hyphen. Is that still valid?

Comment: @dognose OP stated pretty clearly with words what his requirements are. The post would definitely benefit from examples of what's invalid, but there's no need for more than one request in the comments. If my assumptions (if you can call them that) turn out to be incorrect, I'll edit my post.

Comment: @Roddy A hyphen is a non-digit. I'm not sure how that's not clear.

Comment: Which one has better performance? yours or "(\d+\D+|\D+\d+)", they both work for me. Thanks!

Comment: @user2683524 Try them! As far as I recall, though, look-arounds add a performance hit, so your other one might be better on that front. Depending on how you're using it, though, there may not be a significant difference (in which case, go for whichever you find easier to document & understand).

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
.*(?=.*\d)(?=.*\D).*
```

---

But maybe you don't even need a regex? Depending on the language/tool you're using, you might be able to do something like this:

- Let your input string be `s`. If `s` is empty, it is invalid.
- If the first character of `s` is a digit:

  - Loop through the other characters of `s` until you find a non-digit. If you don't find a non-digit, `s` is invalid.
- Otherwise:

  - Loop through the other characters of `s` until you find a digit. If you don't find a digit, `s` is invalid.
- If you found the appropriate digit/non-digit, `s` is valid.

Answer (score 1):

This here works for me.
It's **(** match1 **|** match2 **)** where **|** means **OR**.

```
(\d+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+\d+)
```

Comment: There's no restriction stating that no symbols or uppercase letters are allowed.

Comment: will also fail for `a1b`.

Comment: For "a1b" it matches "a1" so it can be used to validate

Comment: @dognose It won't match the whole string, but it's not restricted to the start & end. It would match the `a1` part and succeed (it's only being used for validation, anyway).

Comment: @Michelle okay, if "1a-" will be valid, ist fine to match only parts of the string.

Comment: @dognose Fair, it requires a letter but doesn't restrict the entire string to being alphanumeric, so it doesn't fit an interpretation of "non-digit" as "letter" OR as "any non-digit character".

Comment: Thanks. "(\d+\D+|\D+\d+)" is better for me.

Answer (score 0):

By digit and non-digit if you mean (any non-digit character) you can use the character classes `\d` for digit and `\D` which means `[^\d]`. There is no need for a lookaround here though. If you mean a number and a letter, you can use the following. I'm exploding your string for comparison strings. I'm using a group with an `|` operator to allow for digit before letter and vice versa.

```
<?php

$string = 'a1 1a a1b 1ab ab1 1-2 12- -12';
$strings = explode(' ',$string);

$pattern = '!([0-9][A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][0-9])!';

foreach($strings as $tempString){
   if(preg_match($pattern,$tempString)){
      echo "$tempString matches\n";   
   } else {
      echo "$tempString doesn't match\n";      
   }
}


?>
```

**Output**

```
a1 matches
1a matches
a1b matches
1ab matches
ab1 matches
1-2 doesn't match
12- doesn't match
-12 doesn't match
```

If we change to the `\d\D` character classes everything matches.

```
$pattern = '!(\d\D|\D\d)!';
```

**Output**

```
a1 matches
1a matches
a1b matches
1ab matches
ab1 matches
1-2 matches
12- matches
-12 matches
```